# How to save schema data to another collection from route function

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Hello I have less idea in express route as I am new in backend with mongodb.

In the route below I am verifying email by resetting a schema value to true. Now I want to copy the new schema details to another existing collection. How can I do that ?

```
router.get('/:adminId/verifyAdmin',function(req,res){

    console.log('request recieved');
    Admin.findOne( {_id: req.params.adminId })
       .exec()
       .then(admin => {

            const Thing = mongoose.model(admin.companyName);
            const emailTokenn = req.query.id;
            //console.log(emailTokenn);
            Thing.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err) =>{

            if(!err){
                return res.redirect('https://localhost:3000/fw18/index.html');  
            }
            else{
                throw err;
            }                         
          });
       });
});
```

Here I want to pass/copy/save `Thing`collection details to existing collection name `users` in my db.

**EDIT:-** Tried this but getting error export :- `const User = mongoose.model('User');`

```
Thing.updateOne( { emailResetTokenn: emailTokenn },{ $set: { verified: true }},(err) =>{
            if(!err){
                //add Thing Schema  to Users collection
                Thing = mongoose.model(admin);
                var copy = mongoose.model('admin', admin,'User');  

                 admin.save(function(err){});

                return res.redirect('https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/fw18/index.html'); 
            }
```

**Error:-** 
`MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model` correct me .

Answer (score 0):

Http is a stateless protocol. To maintain state of the application you can use

1) session

2) cookies and

3) query string.

On your case, you can handle using session. 
Store information to the session and get stored information from different routes.

Comment: Why I need session when I am trying to copy one collection to another collection?

Comment: Because when you redirect to another page, The variable you are storing information will remove.

Comment: I am not using frontend over here . Also I am not  redirecting. On  route function in express I am just trying to copy schema.

Comment: What do you want after copy schema? create a new schema?

Comment: No, I have an existing schema in a collection which are same. I want to copy schema from `collection_1` to `collection_2`. That's it